# C# equivalent to parse cryptojs

Tags: c#, cryptojs

I'm trying to create C# that does this in CryptoJS

```
var hash   = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(msg, key);
var crypt  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(hash.toString());
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(crypt);
```

My question is in the second statement where hash variable is put into a string then parsed.
Is there an equivalent in C#?  Once parsed how do you encode the result into Utf8.
Thanks

Comment: I strongly suspect you *really* want to call `Convert.ToBase64String` on the hash. I suspect the use of UTF-8 to parse a result is actually broken in that CryptoJS code... the natural result of a hash *isn't* UTF-8-encoded text, it's just binary data

Comment: The current script runs in postman however, when I run it in C# it doesn't return the same result

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that, I'm afraid. As far as I was aware, Postman is just used to make HTTP requests, not to run any code. Please clarify the question, ideally with concrete sample data, or it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. It's also very possible that the Javascript you've got at the moment is losing information, at which point you should fix *that* rather than trying to make the C# behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% if I understand exactly which piece you are looking for here. But there is no such thing as a UTF8 System.String in C#. However when you write a string to a stream you can choose the encoding of the bytes in the stream to be UTF8

For example by passing that encoding as an option to a StreamWriter.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
  writer.Write(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My boss find the answer to this. The difference is that before you return the base64 string using C# you have to change the bytes into hexadecimal.

```
    var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] keyBytes = encoder.GetBytes(key);
    var newlinemsg = action + "\n" + msg;
    byte[] messageBytes = encoder.GetBytes(newlinemsg);

    byte[] hashBytes = new HMACSHA512(keyBytes).ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    var hexString = ToHexString(hashBytes);
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encoder.GetBytes(hexString));
```